# edit column/attributes in sequelize migration

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, database-migration

Hi I'm new to migrations in sequelize, and I'm not sure how to add field/property for attributes. So my scenario is that I have two attributes `sku` & `barcode`, but I forgot to add `unique: true`. Now I need to edit the table, I have tried with `addColumn`, `changeColumn` and `addIndex`, but nothing works. I don't know if my approach is correct or not, please help.

Here my migration approach

```
        "use strict";

    module.exports = {
      async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        /**
         * Add altering commands here.
         *
         * Example:
         * await queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
         */

        // *********** received duplicate error  ***********
        // await queryInterface.addColumn("Products", "sku", {
        //   unique: true,
        //   type: Sequelize.STRING,
        //   allowNull: false,
        //   validate: {
        //     notNull: {
        //       msg: "Product SKU cannot be empty",
        //     },
        //     notEmpty: {
        //       msg: "Product SKU cannot be empty",
        //     },
        //   },
        // });
        // await queryInterface.addColumn("Products", "barcode", {
        //   unique: true,
        //   type: Sequelize.STRING,
        //   allowNull: false,
        //   validate: {
        //     notNull: {
        //       msg: "Product barcode cannot be empty",
        //     },
        //     notEmpty: {
        //       msg: "Product barcode cannot be empty",
        //     },
        //   },
        // });

        // ***************** received Cannot create property 'fields' ***********
        // await queryInterface.addIndex("Products", "sku", {
        //   unique: true,
        // });
        // await queryInterface.addIndex("Products", "barcode", {
        //   unique: true,
        // });

        // **************** received Validation error *************
        await queryInterface.changeColumn("Products", "sku", {
          unique: true,
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          validate: {
            notNull: {
              msg: "Product SKU cannot be empty",
            },
            notEmpty: {
              msg: "Product SKU cannot be empty",
            },
          },
        });
        await queryInterface.changeColumn("Products", "barcode", {
          unique: true,
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          validate: {
            notNull: {
              msg: "Product barcode cannot be empty",
            },
            notEmpty: {
              msg: "Product barcode cannot be empty",
            },
          },
        });
      },

      async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        /**
         * Add reverting commands here.
         *
         * Example:
         * await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
         */
        // await queryInterface.removeColumn("Products", "sku");
        // await queryInterface.removeColumn("Products", "barcode");
      },
    };
```

Here how my model looks like:

```
        "use strict";
    const { Model } = require("sequelize");
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      class Product extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
          // define association here
          Product.belongsTo(models.Brand, {
            foreignKey: "brandId",
          });

          Product.belongsTo(models.Category, {
            foreignKey: "categoryId",
            as: "Category",
          });

          Product.belongsTo(models.Category, {
            foreignKey: "subcategoryId",
            as: "Subcategory",
          });

          Product.belongsToMany(models.Tag, {
            through: models.ProductTag,
            foreignKey: "productId",
          });

          Product.hasMany(models.ProductInfo, {
            foreignKey: "productId",
          });

          Product.hasMany(models.ProductPhoto, {
            foreignKey: "productId",
          });

          Product.hasMany(models.ProductStockHistory, {
            foreignKey: "productId",
          });

          Product.hasMany(models.Trolley, {
            foreignKey: "productId",
            targetKey: "id",
          });

          Product.hasMany(models.Wishlist, {
            foreignKey: "productId",
            targetKey: "id",
          });

          Product.belongsToMany(models.PromoPrice, {
            through: models.ProductPromoPrice,
            foreignKey: "ProductId",
          });

          Product.hasOne(models.ProductPromoPrice, {
            foreignKey: "ProductId",
            as: "SpecialPrice",
          });
        }
      }
      Product.init(
        {
          sku: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product SKU cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product SKU cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          barcode: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product barcode cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product barcode cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product name cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product name cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product description cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product description cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          brandId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product brandId cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product brandId cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          categoryId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product categoryId cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product categoryId cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          subcategoryId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product subcategoryId cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product subcategoryId cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          unit: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product unit cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product unit cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          price: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product price cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product price cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          notes: DataTypes.STRING,
          photoURL: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product photo URL cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product photo URL cannot be empty",
              },
              isUrl: {
                msg: "Invalid product photo URL",
              },
            },
          },
          videoURL: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            validate: {
              isUrl: {
                msg: "Invalid product video URL",
              },
            },
          },
          isActive: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product isActive cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product isActive cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          stock: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notNull: {
                msg: "Product stock cannot be empty",
              },
              notEmpty: {
                msg: "Product stock cannot be empty",
              },
            },
          },
          reservedStock: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          sold: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0,
          },
          firestoreId: DataTypes.STRING,
          buyPrice: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
          },
        },
        {
          hooks: {
            beforeCreate(Product, options) {
              Product.stock = Product.stock || 0;
              Product.reservedStock = 0;
            },
          },
          sequelize,
          modelName: "Product",
          // edited here
          paranoid: true,
        }
      );
      return Product;
    };
```

I just need to add `unique: true` in `sku` & `barcode`, please help. Thanks

**EDITED**
here is what I received in terminal when I use `addConstraint`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the queryInterface API here [addConstraint](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-addConstraint) [removeConstraint](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-removeConstraint)

A transaction was made to ensure that all the queries succeed together. The name field in the second parameter of **queryInterface.addConstraint** can be anything. If any two columns have the same name of constraint, then a composite constraint will be created.

```
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction((transaction) => {
      return Promise.all([
        queryInterface.addConstraint("Products", {
          fields: ["barcode"],
          type: "unique",
          name: "Products_barcode_uk",
          transaction,
        }),
        queryInterface.addConstraint("Products", {
          fields: ["sku"],
          type: "unique",
          name: "Products_sku_uk",
          transaction,
        }),
      ]);
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction((transaction) => {
      return Promise.all([
        queryInterface.removeConstraint("Products", "Products_barcode_uk", {
          fields: ["barcode"],
          transaction,
        }),
        queryInterface.removeConstraint("Products", "Products_sku_uk", {
          fields: ["sku"],
          transaction,
        }),
      ]);
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: The constraint name helps during undoing migrations.

Comment: hi I received same error `ERROR: Validation error`

Comment: Adding the error you received (perhaps a snapshot) may help people understand the issue better.

Comment: hi I edited & added screenshot of the error

Comment: Thank you for adding that. You probably received the error because 2 or more rows in your table have the same value for either barcode or sku.

Comment: yes my friend you are correct, in my table I have same value. Thanks so much for the help